# When I add migration I get this error with .NET 7 Windows Forms app

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, entity-framework, .net-7.0

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
namespace ManegmentSystemCompany.Data.Context
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Catogry> Catogry { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Custemer> Custemer { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Employee> employees { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Pruducts> pruducts { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Stores> stores { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Supplier> suppliers { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=WhereHouseDb; Integrated Security=true");
        }
    }
}
```

After I run `add-migration`, I get this error. I could not find a fix for it - help me please.

> No suitable constructor was found for entity type 'Font'. The following constructors had parameters that could not be bound to properties of the entity type:
>
> Cannot bind 'info', 'context' in 'Font(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)'
> Cannot bind 'prototype', 'newStyle' in 'Font(Font prototype, FontStyle newStyle)'
> Cannot bind 'family', 'emSize', 'style', 'unit' in 'Font(FontFamily family, float emSize, FontStyle style, GraphicsUnit unit)'
> Cannot bind 'family', 'emSize', 'style', 'unit', 'gdiCharSet' in 'Font(FontFamily family, float emSize, FontStyle style, GraphicsUnit unit, byte gdiCharSet)'
> Cannot bind 'family', 'emSize', 'style', 'unit', 'gdiCharSet', 'gdiVerticalFont' in 'Font(FontFamily family, float emSize, FontStyle style, GraphicsUnit unit, byte gdiCharSet, bool gdiVerticalFont)'
> Cannot bind 'familyName', 'emSize', 'style', 'unit', 'gdiCharSet' in 'Font(string familyName, float emSize, FontStyle style, GraphicsUnit unit, byte gdiCharSet)'
> Cannot bind 'familyName', 'emSize', 'style', 'unit', 'gdiCharSet', 'gdiVerticalFont' in 'Font(string familyName, float emSize, FontStyle style, GraphicsUnit unit, byte gdiCharSet, bool gdiVerticalFont)'
> Cannot bind 'family', 'emSize', 'style' in 'Font(FontFamily family, float emSize, FontStyle style)'
> Cannot bind 'family', 'emSize', 'unit' in 'Font(FontFamily family, float emSize, GraphicsUnit unit)'
> Cannot bind 'family', 'emSize' in 'Font(FontFamily family, float emSize)'
> Cannot bind 'familyName', 'emSize', 'style', 'unit' in 'Font(string familyName, float emSize, FontStyle style, GraphicsUnit unit)'

Comment: can you please format your question properly, my eyes are paining after taking an attempt to read it

Comment: **Typo** alerts - it should be **Management** - not "Manegment...." ; **Customer** - not "Custemer" - **Category**, not "Catogry" - **Products**, not "Pruducts"  ......

Comment: sorry my english is not good but i think this error not see whate u say and it will add whate i write if u know u can help

Comment: am added images to see whate i do in code and projects not error found and am build it note see any error , this error am get it when am add migration to try connect database

Answer (score 1):

> No suitable constructor was found for entity type 'Font'

Do you expect Font to be stored in the database? If so, it needs a constructor that EF can use to create instances.  The rules are documented here:

> It's possible to define a constructor with parameters and have EF Core
> call this constructor when creating an instance of the entity. The
> constructor parameters can be bound to mapped properties, or to
> various kinds of services to facilitate behaviors like lazy-loading.

[Entity types with constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/constructors).

If you don't expect to store Font in the database, you need to [exclude it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/entity-properties?tabs=data-annotations%2Cwithout-nrt#included-and-excluded-properties).